# Process whitespace in specific ANTLR parser rule but skip it in all other cases

Tags: antlr, whitespace

maybe someone can help me on this. I have written an ANTLR grammar which in short looks like this:

```
grammar myGrammar;
file: mystring+;
mystring: name EQUALITYSIGN DOUBLEQUOTE stringVal DOUBLEQUOTE SEMICOLON;
stringVal: (CHAR | INT)*;
name: CHAR | INT;
EQUALITYSIGN : '=';
DOUBLEQUOTE: '"';
SEMICOLON: ';';
WHITESPACE : ' ' -> skip;
NEWLINE : '\r'? '\n' -> skip;
CHAR : ~[ \t\r\n\\\[\]";=]+;
```

I have different parser rules for other data types but considering the String type, I would like to NOT skip the whitespaces.

For instance, an input might look like this:

```
string1 = " a ";
```

In this case, I want the whitespaces before and after the "a" to be preserved. So, anything inside the double quotes, shall be preserved as it is.

I have tried to do it with defined channels but apparently, I am doing something wrong.

Any ideas?

Thanx in advance!

Comment: I don't use ANTLR, so this is just a guess: Have you tried `stringVal: DOUBLEQUOTE  (CHAR | INT)* DOUBLEQUOTE ;`? (and then take out the DOUBLEQUOTEs from `mystring`, of course).

Comment: Thanx but that doesn't make any difference. The problem is that I define whitespaces to be skipped in general but want to make an exception for the myString rule. And I haven't quite succeeded in doing that, yet.

Comment: I believe Bart has it - I was on the same line of thought as him, I just wasn't sure how ANTLR distinguishes between lexer and parser rules.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make `stringVal` a lexer rule:

```
STRING: '"' ~'"'* '"';
```

and remove `DOUBLEQUOTE`.

Comment: Hi Bart, thank you - that worked. However, I have another data type in the same grammar which is almost exactly like the string but doesn't come in double quotes:  `anotherType : key EQUALITYSIGN value SEMICOLON; value: (CHAR | EQUALITYSIGN)*; `.  The trick with the lexer rule doen't work on this one.  An input example would be:  `anotherValue = value(1) + value(2);`

Comment: And is there a possibility to still retain the parser rule for the string and use hidden channels? My design requires the value to be parsed separately: `public void exitStringVal(MyParser.StringValContext ctx) { value = getValue(ctx);}`

Comment: Hi, I got it to work for the other type, too now. I added the following to my Loader class that extends my BaseListener class: `value = ctx.start.getInputStream().getText(Interval.of(ctx.start.getStartIndex(), ctx.stop.getStopIndex()));`